# What are the SEO ramifications of duplicate content on the same page?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot, googlebot-mobile

My question has some similarities to this [one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52965/duplicate-content-on-the-same-page-seo-ramifications). But since I am asking about a very specific type of section on the page I think it warrants some thought as to whether the approach I am looking to take is considered spammy.

**Question:**
I am wondering if there are any penalties for having duplicate content on the SAME PAGE.

**Scenario:** 
The mock-ups provided have an FAQ section in the sidebar of a topic page on the Desktop view. However, on the mobile view, the FAQ section now renders somewhere in the main article body.

My initial instinct was to hide and show the respective sections based on breakpoints, but they would both still exist in the DOM. I was informed that this isn't ideal for SEO, but the only information I am able to find discusses the penalties of having duplicate content on the same domain and not the same page.

**So I guess is this actually bad for SEO, or are crawlers smart enough not to care? The two sections never appear on the page at the same time.**

Another possibility we are exploring is keeping the FAQ in the sidebar, and on mobile having a call-to-action section that says "Click to read FAQs" and once the user clicks, dynamically removing the markup from inside the hidden sidebar FAQ and placing it inside the section that was just clicked. This way the markup is never present int the pages DOM twice at the same time... but since crawlers can execute JavaScript... would that still potentially count as duplicate content?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of the question you linked. The answer there applies here as well.

Answer (score 1):

> if there are any penalties for having duplicate content on the SAME
>   PAGE

No, your site gets no direct malus for DC on the same url.

But, indirectly, it does, because this is a kind of suboptimal practice, negatively influencing the loading+rendering performance of the page. Maintaining of duplicated content on the same url makes your source code becoming longer, takes more time to be rendered and so on.

The best practice is to manage same content to be displayed for several devices with CSS, not with duplication and `display:none;`.